# Regular expression for replacing a specific phone number

Tags: javascript, regex

So I'm working on a regular expression that can change a specific phone number on a website.
I'm slowly getting there, but I cannot figure out how to catch the following numbers: (085)-4017877
(085)4017877.

Also tools like regexr.com tell me the regex catches both numbers here:
085-4017877
But on my current setup it does not catch the first number. Any ideas on why this could be?

Current Regex:
\85[-.\s]?4017877\g

The zero at the front of the numbers is ignored on purpose.

What it should catch:

085-4017877
085-4017877
(085)-4017877
(085)4017877
085 4017877
+31854017877

Test:
http://regexr.com/39v0b

```
       //step through dom
    function recurseDOM(scope, newText, patt)
{
    var i = 0, nodes, node;
    if(scope.childNodes)
    {
        nodes = scope.childNodes;
        for(i;i<nodes.length;i++)
        {
            node = nodes[i];
            if(node.nodeType === 3)
            {
                //is a text node
                checkTextNode(node, newText, patt);
            }
            if(node.childNodes)
            {
                //loop through child nodes if child nodes are found
                recurseDOM(node, newText, patt);
            }
            node = null;
        }
        nodes = null;
    }
}

//Find and replace
function checkTextNode(node, newText, patt)
{
    var text = node.data;
    var test = patt.test(text);

    if(test)
    {
        //match found, replace node's textual data with specified string
        node.data = text.replace(patt, newText);
        newText = null;
        text = null;
    }
    test = null;
}
```

Code Im currently using to replace the number

Comment: Where does the "+31" come from? Unless that's the default country number.

Comment: Also, what are you replacing it with?

Comment: You can't just ignore the 0, or the opening parentheses, you'd end up leaving these characters in after the replacement operation and the results are assuredly not what you'd want.

Comment: Hi Sweaver, in this case it can be ignored. I wasn´t very clear in my OP but only the last 9 numbers change. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close, this one should catch all your cases:

```
/85\)?[- ]?4017877/g
```

It just adds an optional parenthesis before the dash/space character class.

Comment: Or put the closing parentheses inside the already optional character set.

Comment: @Ja͢ck Doing that directly wouldn't work unless the ? were changed to a * (or {0,2}), which would then admit a larger pattern i.e. 085-)4017877 would then be matched.

Comment: Hi Doug, thanks. That seems to work. Funny thing is that it catches all on the testing setup at regexr.com. But in real live it doesn´t catch the first sequence of 854017877 in the html: `<a href="tel:+31854017877">085-4017877</a>`. Any idea why? But maybe thats a problem for a different questions.

Comment: Are you hoping that it will change the text within the `href` attribute?  That'll be contained in an elementType of 1, so you'll need to pick that out with something like http://codepen.io/dougluce/pen/PwqZVM

Comment: doesn't account for the +31 country code and also leaves any opening 0 and ( hanging.

Comment: Hopefully that's obvious enough for the OP to notice and address. I'm answering the asked question.

Comment: Hi Doug, thanks. That last piece of code works great. And yes in this case the leading zero can be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is too simple for the patterns you're trying to catch, this regex will match all your test cases:

```
/(\+31)?(\()?0?85(\)-?| |-)?4017877/
```

I have made you a [test here](http://regexr.com/39v0h)

Should you want a generic regex for this numbers, need to replace digits with '\d':

```
/(\+\d\d)?(\()?\d?\d\d(\)-?| |-)?\d\d\d\d\d\d\d/
```

Comment: The specific regex works, but the generic one matches any 10 consecutive digits (0123456789) - just take it out, he is matching that one number anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I'd use:

```
(?:\d{3}\s?|\(\d{3}\)|\+\d{4})-?\d{7}
```

Breakdown:

- `(?:`  -  open non-capture group, for alternate patterns to match (to keep things neat)
- `\d{3}\s?|`  -  match full area code
- `\(\d{3}\)|`  -  match area code surrounded by parentheses
- `\+\d{4}`  -  match country code and area code
- `)`  -  close non-capture group
- `-?`  -  hyphen zero or one time
- `\d{7}`  -  match the last seven digits

Now you can easily change the pattern without headaches by modifying the non-capture group alternates.

Comment: matches any 10 digits in a row, like 0000000000 or 0123456789.